# Execute ApplciationRunner run only in dev profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

How do I create dummy data when the application starts only in dev profile?

I'm following [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1) to work with profiles in spring boot. I need to create dummy data when the application starts, but only in the dev profile. How do I achieve this?

My class implements `ApplicationRunner` and overrides the `run` method to create the data. I've tried to use the `@Profile("dev")` annotation as in the article but the data is created irrespective of the active profile.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //handles user saving

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Profile("dev")
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Dummy User");
        userService.save(user);
    }

}
```

In `application.properties`, I have

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

A dummy user should be created only when the active profile is `dev` but it is being created in `test` profile as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Profile` should be marked with `@Bean` or `@Component` or its stereotype (i.e `@Serivce` , `@Controller` , `@Repository` etc.)

Simply change it to :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //handles user saving


    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner devApplicationRunner(){
        return arg->{
           User user = new User();
           user.setName("Dummy User");
           userService.save(user);
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The code of DEV ApplicationRunner will only run if DEV profile is enabled such as through application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
  }

}
```

or

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;
...
env.setActiveProfiles("dev");
```

and `@Profile` only for classes

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this will set the active profile. But where do I save the dummy user? And how do I define it to do so only in dev profile?

Comment: You can make class, annotate it via Component and Profile("dev"), and annotate method with your code with @PostConstract

Comment: @YaroslavLukianenko I downvoted, it just sets the active profile. BTW, both ways are clumsy, we usually define this in a configuration file.